# 'We are neither.' Is that correct?

Tags: neither-nor

I am composing a sentence like: 'Some people think we are *this*, some think we are *that*...'. 
Then I want to say that we are neither *this* nor *that*. 
 Can I write it in short like this: 'But we are neither.'? Or should I alway add nor after neither, even in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you could say for example

*"Some people are pro gun control, others are anti gun control.  We are neither."*

Answer (score -1):

In this case, *neither* is acting as an adverb. So yes, this is correct.

Try using an alternate adverb, *aboard*. We are aboard. That works. It might sound more 'correct' but only because we think adverb first with *aboard* and one might think determiner first with *neither*.

To be clear: it isn't idiomatic, an ungrammatical construction we've just gotten used to. It's straight up correct.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality for its length and content. My take is it is borderline. Your last statement begs for formal support. Can you provide some support for your position? And *aboard* might be regarded an orphaned preposition also. A unique adverb would be better. [aboard](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/aboard-part-of-speech-and-its-replacement-for-on-board)